# Customized compass needle in google maps for Android v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I would like to create a customized compass needle in my android google maps app using v2
I also want to decide where to put it
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly this is possible. Disable default compass via [`setCompassEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setCompassEnabled%28boolean%29) and draw your own. Use sensors to make it point in the right direction.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks!
It would be nice if someone can provide a nice example as well